# why is this page crashing iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, crash, raphael

http://bit.ly/Z7YPj7

It works fine on the desktop everywhere, and also on Android. But on the iPhone Simulator, the culprit appears to be in the file: `js/the-anim36.js` (which queues a whole bunch of Raphael SVG animations).

I'm monkeying around with Safari 6's "Develop" menu, which can now log info from the XCodes's iOS Simulator, which i downloaded and fired up. But I'm getting absolutely nothing in the javascript console, and a hard crash in the simulator each and every time I open the html file. I have to "Reset Content and Settings" each time I try to open the file. I'm frankly lost here, admittedly a novice at debugging in general (and also probably spoiled by Chrome.) Any pointers on what's possibly going on here would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run out of memory really fast on iOS. Run it through the Chrome profiler and see what you're memory usage looks like. I bet it's using > 10mb of ram. In which case you're probably toast!

Check out this informative article, that claims after about 6mb of ram, you will crash mobile safari:
http://cubiq.org/testing-memory-usage-on-mobile-safari

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the link. I had no idea those vectors were so RAM hungry!

Answer (score 0):

I observe that when I open that page my laptop fan run on high.  The thing is consuming a lot of CPU (and likely a lot of RAM) and may simply be exceeding the allowable resource limits on iOS.  If not running out of RAM it could be causing the foreground process to run too long, triggering the logic that cancels "looping" apps.